# How to get time and date in filname when using split_recording on raspberry pi

Tags: python, time, filenames

How can I insert time and date in the filname when i do a split_recording?
I have defined tid as time, and if i insert it as camera.start_recording('1.' + tid + '.h264') it works only for the first file.
As it is under, it does not work.

```
import picamera
import time

tid = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

camera = picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(640, 480))
camera.start_recording('1.h264')
camera.wait_recording(5)
for i in range(2, 11):
camera.split_recording('%d.' + tid +'.h264' % i)
camera.wait_recording(5)
camera.stop_recording()
```

The one over gives error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./recording.py", line 17, in 
camera.split_recording('%d.' + tid +'.h264' % i)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Comment: `'%d.' + tid +'.h264' % i` only applies the substitution to `'.h264'`, which has nothing that needs to be substituted.  You'd need to write this as `('%d.' + tid +'.h264') % i` or `'%d.' % i + tid +'.h264'`.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was (('%d.' + tid +'.h264') % i)  Learned something new today. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was 
    (('%d.' + tid +'.h264') % i)

Thank you to  jasonharper for the solution.